# The audio is not playing pygame

Tags: python, audio, path, pygame, audio-player

This is my code:

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load(r'C:\Users\mahad\Desktop\venvdir\analog.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
print("end")
```

I want to play a simple mp3 file.
But it is not opening for some reason.
Can't figure out where I am wrong :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `play()` call is non-blocking, i.e. if you immediately exit the application (as in your example) you will never hear the music.

If you try this:

```
from pygame import mixer
import time

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load(r'C:\Users\mahad\Desktop\venvdir\analog.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(5)
print("end")
```

you will at least hear five seconds of music.

In a proper game application you will have to start the music and then do other stuff - and not immediately exit the application.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your program is exiting before the sound can be played (the `play` function is asynchronous). If those lines are the entire program and you only want to play an `mp3`, change your code to:

```
from pygame import mixer
from pygame import time

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load(r'C:\Users\mahad\Desktop\venvdir\analog.mp3')
mixer.music.play()
while mixer.music.get_busy():
    time.Clock().tick(10)
```

This will wait until the end of the audio stream.